# Не получается перегрузить оператор сложения в классе. Process finished with exit code -1073740940

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, стек

Задание состоит в том, чтобы перегрузить оператор + чтобы он работал как метод Push(). Этот метод я реализовал и все работает, есть и перегрузка оператора присваивания, программа компилируется без ошибок и все работает, если я напишу

> st.Push(i)

, но если

> st = st + i

, компилируется тоже, но уже в конце работы программа возвращает: Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374). И вывода на экран самого стека нет. Пробовал по разному перегружать оператор + и = с разными возвращаемыми значениями и по ссылке, и по значению. Если погуглить ошибку, то там только про PyCharm что-то и Python и что это ошибка под Windows когда нарушение доступа, и решение там не связано с C++.

### Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"

int main()
{
    Stack st;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        //st.Push(i);
        st = st + i;
    }


    while (!st.Empty())
    {
        std::cout << st.Pop() << ' ';
    }




    return 0;
}
```

### Stack.h

```
#ifndef _STACK_H_
#define _STACK_H_

class Stack
{
 private:
    const short EMPTY = -1;
    struct stack
    {
        ptrdiff_t* array = nullptr;
        ptrdiff_t size = 0;
        ptrdiff_t capacity = 0;
    };
    stack st;
    ptrdiff_t top;
 public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();

    void Push(ptrdiff_t val);
    ptrdiff_t Pop();
    ptrdiff_t Top() const;
    bool Empty() const;

    //To tell the compiler that a certain constructor
    // may not be used to implicitly cast an expression to its class type.
    explicit operator bool() const;
    friend Stack operator+(Stack l, ptrdiff_t r);
    ptrdiff_t operator--();
    ptrdiff_t operator--(int);
    Stack& operator=(const Stack& other);

};

#endif //_STACK_H_
```

### Stack.cpp

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"

Stack::Stack() : top(-1)
{
    // Stack memory size starts at 5
    st.array = new ptrdiff_t[5];
    st.capacity = 5;
}

void Stack::Push(ptrdiff_t val)
{
    if (st.size < st.capacity)
    {
        st.array[++top] = val;
        st.size++;
    }
        /* if size == capacity, you create a new array of size capacity * 2,
         * which can handle write operations without allocating and deleting memory every so often  */
    else if (st.size == st.capacity)
    {
        auto* new_st = new ptrdiff_t[st.capacity * 2];
        std::copy(st.array, st.array + st.size, new_st);
        delete[] st.array;
        st.array = new_st;
        st.array[++top] = val;
        st.size++;
        st.capacity *= 2;
    }

}

ptrdiff_t Stack::Pop()
{
    if (top == -1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Stack is empty" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* if size > capacity / 2, then you create a new array of size capacity / 2 ,
     * which can withstand write operations without allocating and deleting memory every so often */
    if (st.size < st.capacity / 2)
    {
        auto* new_st = new ptrdiff_t[st.capacity / 2];
        std::copy(st.array, st.array + st.size, new_st);
        delete[] st.array;
        st.array = new_st;
        st.capacity /= 2;
    }
    st.size--;
    return st.array[top--];
}

bool Stack::Empty() const
{
    return top == EMPTY;
}

ptrdiff_t Stack::Top() const
{
    if (top == -1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Stack is empty" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return st.array[top];
}

Stack::operator bool() const
{
    return top != EMPTY;
}

ptrdiff_t Stack::operator--()
{
    return this->Pop();
}

ptrdiff_t Stack::operator--(int)
{
    auto old = st.array[top];
    this->Pop();
    return old;
}

Stack operator+(Stack l, const ptrdiff_t r)
{
    if (l.st.size < l.st.capacity)
    {
        l.st.array[++l.top] = r;
        l.st.size++;
    }
        /* if size == capacity, you create a new array of size capacity * 2,
         * which can handle write operations without allocating and deleting memory every so often  */
    else if (l.st.size == l.st.capacity)
    {
        auto* new_st = new ptrdiff_t[l.st.capacity * 2];
        std::copy(l.st.array, l.st.array + l.st.size, new_st);
        delete[] l.st.array;
        l.st.array = new_st;
        l.st.array[++l.top] = r;
        l.st.size++;
    }
    return l;
}

Stack& Stack::operator=(const Stack& other)
{
    if (this != &other) // protect against invalid self-assignment
    {
        // 1: allocate new memory and copy the elements
        auto* new_st = new ptrdiff_t[other.st.size];
        std::copy(other.st.array, other.st.array + other.st.size, new_st);

        // 2: deallocate old memory
        delete[] st.array;

        // 3: assign the new memory to the object
        st.array = new_st;
        st.size = other.st.size;
    }
    // by convention, always return *this
    return *this;
}

Stack::~Stack()
{
    delete[] st.array;
}
```

Comment: У вас нет конструктора копирования, выполняется копирование поверхностное (путем присвоения указателей), потом в деструкторе возникают проблемы. И еще - зачем дублировать код? Почему бы в операторе не вызывать просто `Push()`?

Comment: Сделал, вот = 
`Stack& Stack::operator=(const Stack& other)
{
 if (this != &other) // protect against invalid self-assignment
 {
  st.size = other.st.size;
  st = other.st;
  top = other.top;
  st.size = other.st.size;
 }

 return *this;
}`
А вот копирование

`Stack::Stack(const Stack& stack) : st(stack.st), top(stack.top)`

Но почему-то после первого елемента по отладке, вызывается `delete[]`
И вот такое:
**Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)**

Comment: Ваше копирование копирует указатели, а не содержимое. В результате в деструкторе вы дважды пытаетесь освободить одну и ту же память и получаете неприятности.

Answer (score 0):

А почему Вы уверены, что проблема именно в +? Проблема может быть и в другом месте. На чём Вы тестировали присваивание? На присваивании одной переменной-стека другой такой же переменной? А теперь Вам надо присвоить переменной значение временного объекта, после чего выбросить оригинал.

```
    Stack st1;
    Stack st2;
    Stack st2.puch(20);
    st1=st2+40;
```

Вот здесь в последней строчке надо st2+40 присвоить st1, потом st2+40 удалить и освободить занятую этим временным объектом память. st1 получит готовое новое значение, в st2 останется старое значение, а st2+40 нигде больше не нужно. Но + до вызова = уже завершился и ничего за собой подчистить не может. Залогируйте все вызовы конструкторов, методов, операторов и деструкторов со всеми адресами параметров и операндов, в тот же лог положите из вызывающего кода адреса всех своих именованных объектов. А потом уж разбирайте, где что не так. И сначала разнеся сумму и слагаемое по разным объектам.